# Transferring data from TextBox to the header of DataGridViewCheckBox

Tags: checkbox, datagridview, vb.net-2010

We wanted to let the user to input a value in textbox  and then when the button was click the value inputted in the textbox will be transferred in the header of a dgvcheckbox. So please help us in solving this problem . . we've been trying to solved this but unfortunately we can't.

Answer (score 0):

you can use HeaderText property of columns
eg

```
            datagridview.Columns["columnName"].HeaderText = 'yourString';
```